# Singleton NSWindowController won't reopen window after close

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, singleton, nswindow

I have a singleton NSWindowController (ProjectInfoHUDController) that won't reopen after it has been closed. The object is persisting in memory which I know because any calls made to `[ProjectInfoHUDController sharedInstance]` both before and after the window has been closed return the same memory address. Both `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` and `controller.window.isVisible = YES` do nothing.

Comment: Is the window configured to be released when closed? That’s the default behaviour for windows that aren’t panels.

Comment: Can your window be a key window? Does `-orderFront:` work?

Comment: It is not. I even added setReleasedWhenClosed:NO to my code, but it made absolutely no difference. I also read somewhere that this method has no effect on windows that are mediated by an NSWindowController (as mine is), but I'm not sure if that's true or not.

Comment: No luck with -orderFront: either.

Comment: Ah, that’s true. Window closing behaviour is different with window controllers that aren’t part of a document-based application.

Comment: Is `-window` non `nil` after having closed the window? Can you get information from it, e.g. `-frame` or `-title`?

Comment: Okay, this is getting weirder. It looks like the window (and any of its info) is returning nil both before and after it gets correctly displayed the first time as well as any subsequent times it tries to show itself.

Comment: Okay, so now I'm totally embarrassed about my stupidity, but apparently, I didn't have the window connected in IB. Thanks anyway for all your help.

Comment: I think you should write that as an answer and accept it so that the question appears resolved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out the window was not connected in IB. Another lesson in looking for the obvious solution first.

Comment: What connection was missing?  I keep coming across this problem and seem to be fixing it randomly, rather than learning exactly which connection I'm missing.

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember. I asked this question almost a year ago when I had just started learning objective-c development. I'm guessing I didn't have the window connected to the `window` property of its corresponding `NSWindowController` (likely the file's owner).

Comment: Just ran across this issue after pulling my hair out about it. Sean was correct in this case. It was caused by not connecting the Window to your File's Owner.